# figuring out the conversions from UIKit coordinates to SKScene coordinates

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody, skscene

I am new to SpriteKit but not to iOS. I'm having a great deal of difficulty figuring out the conversions from UIKit coordinates to SKScene coordinates. In addition, their relations to the units used for the SpriteKit physics engine evades me.

Here's what I'm trying to do: I am launching a sprite with an initial velocity in both x and y directions. The sprite should start near the screen's bottom left corner (portrait mode) and leave near the bottom right corner. Another sprite should appear somewhere on the previous sprite's trajectory. This sprite is static.

[image]

The blue frame is the screen boundary, the black curve is the first sprite's trajectory and the red circle is the static sprite.

Now using the screen as 640 x 960. In my SKScene's didMoveToView: method I set the gravity as such:

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0f, -2.0f);
```

Then I make the necessary calculations for velocity and position:
"t" is time from left corner to right; 
"y" is the maximum height of the trajectory; 
"a" is the acceleration; 
"vx" is velocity in the x direction; 
"vy" is velocity in the y direction;

and

"Tstatic" is the time at which the dynamic sprite will be at the static sprite's position;
"Xstatic" is the static sprite's x-position;
"Ystatic" is the static sprite's y-position;

```
-(void)addSpritePair {

float vx, vy, t, Tstatic, a, Xstatic, Ystatic, y;

a = -2.0;
t = 5.0;
y = 800.0;
vx = 640.0/t;
vy = (y/t) - (1/8)*a*t;
Tstatic = 1.0;
Xstatic = vx*Tstatic;
Ystatic = vy*Tmark + 0.5*a*Tstatic*Tstatic;

[self spriteWithVel:CGVectorMake(vx, vy) andPoint:CGPointMake(xmark, ymark)];

}

-(void)spriteWithVel:(CGVector)velocity andPoint:(CGPoint)point{

SKSpriteNode *staticSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball1"];
staticSprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5, .5);
staticSprite.position = point;
staticSprite.name = @"markerNode";
staticSprite.zPosition = 1.0;

SKSpriteNode *dynamicSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball2"];
dynamicSprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5, .5);
dynamicSprite.position = CGPointMake(1 ,1);
dynamicSprite.zPosition = 2.0;
dynamicSprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:hoop.size.width/2];
dynamicSprite.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
dynamicSprite.physicsBody.velocity = velocity;
dynamicSprite.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
dynamicSprite.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
dynamicSprite.physicsBody.mass = 1.0f;
dynamicSprite.markerPoint = point;
dynamicSprite.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0f;
dynamicSprite.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;
dynamicSprite.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0.0f;
dynamicSprite.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0f;

[self addChild:hoop];
[self addChild:marker];
```

}

When I execute the code, the following happens:

[image]

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: UIKit origin: top left with positive Y extending downards. Sprite Kit origin: lower left with positive Y extending upwards. Plus consider that many nodes (including sprites) have a default anchor point of 0.5,0.5 which puts the texture centered on the node's position. Ie only one quarter of a sprite that's a child of the scene and has the default position 0,0 is visible on the screen. It looks like you assume that the textures extend solely up and to the right as they do in UIKit.

Comment: Alright I will keep that in mind! Why is it though, that instead of going to 800, the sprite only goes to about 10?